# Property of strongly convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis

Given $f$ is strongly convex with convexity parameter $\sigma$ and $\displaystyle x_0=\arg\min_{x}f(x)$, how do we arrive at the following inequality:
$$f(x)\ge f(x_0)+\frac{\sigma}{2}\|x-x_0\|^2$$
Note that $f$ is not assumed to be differentiable.

I tried to prove by contradiction as follows:
\begin{align}
f(\theta x+(1-\theta)x_0)&\le\theta f(x)+(1-\theta)f(x_0)-\frac{\sigma}{2}\theta(1-\theta)\|x-x_0\|^2\\
&=f(x_0)+\theta\left(f(x)-f(x_0)-\frac{\sigma}{2}\|x-x_0\|^2\right)+\frac{\sigma}{2}\theta^2\|x-x_0\|^2\\
&\qquad\vdots\\
&<f(x_0)
\end{align}
but I am unable to get the last inequality above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. First, if $\sigma=0$ the claimed inequality 
$$
f(x)\ge f(x_0)+\frac\sigma2|| x-x_0||^2
$$
is obviously true. So assume $\sigma>0$. Suppose that the claimed inequality does not hold for all $x$. Then there exists $x_1$ such that the quantity
$$
\delta:=f(x_1)-f(x_0)-\frac\sigma2||x_1-x_0||^2
$$
is strictly negative. Note that $x_1\ne x_0$ (why?). Following your line of reasoning, we have for every $\theta\in(0,1)$:
$$
\begin{align}
f(x_0)\le f(\theta x_1+(1-\theta)x_0)&\le\theta f(x_1)+(1-\theta)f(x_0)-\frac{\sigma}{2}\theta(1-\theta)\|x_1-x_0\|^2\\
&=f(x_0)+\theta\left(f(x_1)-f(x_0)-\frac{\sigma}{2}\|x_1-x_0\|^2\right)+\frac{\sigma}{2}\theta^2\|x_1-x_0\|^2\\
&=f(x_0)+\delta\theta+\frac\sigma2\theta^2||x_1-x_0||^2
\end{align}
$$
Rearrange and conclude that for every $\theta\in(0,1)$,

$$-\delta \le\frac\sigma2\theta\,||x_1-x_0||^2\ .\tag{*}
$$
The LHS of (*) is strictly positive. Now your job is to find a small enough $\theta$ for which (*) cannot be true.

Comment: **Hint:** Take the infimum of the LHS of (*) w.r.t $\theta \in \text{ }]0,1[$.